# How to center a figure without a figure environment?

Tags: graphics, floats, include

I am trying to center a figure which I included directly in the text (it´s only a 2 line table and I didn´t want captations so this was the only way for me to solve the problem). I tried to use \centering before \includegraphic but this also centered the text that followed. Any ideas how to either center the figure without shifting text or find a way to surpress the captation in the figure environment?

Here a minimum example without the figure environment and one within:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\begin{document}

\section{...}
bla bla

\centering
\includegraphics[height=.085\textheight]{Werte_Staumauer.pdf}

\subsection{...}
bla bla 
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\begin{document}

\section{...}
bla bla

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=.3\textheight]{example.jpg}
\caption[]{}
\label{fig.0}
\end{figure}

\subsection{...}
bla bla 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is normal: `\centering` is a *switch*,  valid for the subsequent code within the current group. So either you put put your figure inside a `center` environment, or you put it with the switch inside a group, delimited by a pair of braces, or a pair `\bgroup ... \egroup`.

Comment: Great thank you! \begin{center}  and \end{center} did just what I was looking for

Comment: To not get a caption in a figure environment, don't use `\caption`? Ye, it is as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
\section{...}
bla bla

{%
\centering
\includegraphics[height=.085\textheight]{Werte_Staumauer.pdf} }
  }%

\subsection{...}
```

or

```
\section{...}
bla bla

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=.085\textheight]{Werte_Staumauer.pdf}
\end{center}

\subsection{...}
```

The difference is that the environment adds some vertical spacing.

Another solution consists in using the

```
\InsertBoxC{\includegraphics[height=.085\textheight]{Werte_Staumauer.pdf}}
```

command from the `insbox` set of plain TeX macros (to be loaded with `\input{insbox.tex}`.  This macro  `ends the current line` before inserting the graphic file (or whatever box you insert), then the text continues after the inserted box.

Answer (score 0):

If there are not paragraph indentation (`\parindent` = 0pt), is enough add `\hfil` before the image and one blank line ( or `\par`) after the image.

In case of some paragraph indentation, start the line with  `\noindent`  or the image will be centered only with respect the first lines of paragraphs. Example to test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %dummy text 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %show margins
\setlength{\parindent}{.3\linewidth}  % huge indentation to test
\setlength{\parskip}{2em} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\noindent\hfil\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```